# Regexp for german phone number format

Tags: java, php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I try to get phone numbers from string in german format. But I don't get it to full run. The input text is a full HTML-Page with lots of content, not only the numbers.

Possible Formats:

```
(06442) 3933023     
(02852) 5996-0       
(042) 1818 87 9919   
06442 / 3893023  
06442 / 38 93 02 3     
06442/3839023
042/ 88 17 890 0     
+49 221 549144 – 79  
+49 221 - 542194 79  
+49 (221) - 542944 79
0 52 22 - 9 50 93 10 
+49(0)121-79536 - 77 
+49(0)2221-39938-113 
+49 (0) 1739 906-44  
+49 (173) 1799 806-44
0173173990644
0214154914479
02141 54 91 44 79
01517953677
+491517953677
015777953677
02162 - 54 91 44 79
(02162) 54 91 44 79
```

I have tried:

```
$regex =  '~(?:\+?49|0)(?:\s*\d{3}){2}\s*\d{4,10}~';
if(preg_match_all($regex, $input_imprint , $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
}
```

But it doesn't match only a few formats. I have no idea to do it.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a regex to match all your formats.
I would suggest then to replace all unwanted characters and you got your desired result.

```
(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+)\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))
```

If you need a minimum length to match your numbers, use this:

```
(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))
```

https://regex101.com/r/CAVex8/143

updated, thanks for the suggestion @Willi Mentzel

Comment: the second minus will be interpreted as "until". you should mask it to avoid unwated matches. `(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))` we noticed it when we used it :D. good answer

Comment: Why do you escape all characters in the character class? Why do you put twice the hyphen? That makes your regex unreadable.Moreover a double quantifier `+` & `{6,}` in `([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Be careful this validation also matches `+-+++49 (173) 1799 806-44`

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9]*\/*(\+49)*[ ]*(\([0-9]+\))*([ ]*(-|–)*[ ]*[0-9]+)*
```

Check this link: https://regex101.com/r/CAVex8/1

May introduce some false positives.

Answer (score 1):

This one solved my problem (extracting phone numers from emails):

`r"\+?[0-9]+([0-9]|\/|\(|\)|\-| ){10,}"`

A plus sign optional at the front, followed by at least 1 number, followed by at least 10 numbers or delimiting characters such as `/`, `(`, `)` or `-` or a space.
(There is no official "smallest number of digits" for a telephone number, but I assume they are all at least 11 digits long)

I'm adding this because @Kakul 's solution matched any lien of my text, and using @despecial 's my code would not terminate. (I am guessing it is too computationally expensive for my pc)

Answer (score 1):

**This is no solution for the asked question, just an advice for matching phonenumbers!**

If you are about to store telephone numbers for you first time, then limit the amount of different accepted formats. Get rid of these for example:

```
(06442) 3933023
042/ 88 17 890 0
+49(0)121-79536 - 77
02162 - 54 91 44 79
```

Why?
You need to test more possible ways of inputting an invalid value.

Those formats you absolutely need to concider according to [DIN 5008](https://www.din-5008-richtlinien.de/startseite/telefonnummern/):

```
0873 376461
03748 37682358
05444 347687-350
0764 812632-41
0180 2 12334
0800 5 23234213
+49 30 3432622-113
0179 1111111
```

Here is what I came up with: [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/HvdZcd/1)

```
^(([+]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}[ ]{1}([1-9]{1}[0-9]{1,4}){1}[ ]{1}([1-9]{1}[0-9]{2,6}){1}([ -][0-9]{1,5})?)|([0]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1,4}[ ]{1}[0-9]{1,8}([ -][0-9]{1,8})?)?)
```

Positives:

```
06429 1111
06901 306180
06429 231
0800 3301000
0179 1111111
0873 376461
03748 37682358
05444 347687-350
0764 812632-41
0180 2 12334
0800 5 23234213
+49 6429 1111
+49 39857 2530
+55 11 2666-0054
+300 11 2666-0054
+49 641 20106 0
+49 641 20106
+49 30 3432622-113
```

Negatives:

```
++49 157 184977
+300 11 0000-0000
(06442) 3933023
(02852) 5996-0
(042) 1818 87 9919
06442 / 3893023
06442 / 38 93 02 3
06442/3839023
042/ 88 17 890 0
+49 221 - 542194 79
+49 (221) - 542944 79
0 52 22 - 9 50 93 10
+49(0)121-79536 - 77
+49(0)2221-39938-113
+49 (0) 1739 906-44
+49 (173) 1799 806-44
0173173990644
0214154914479
01517953677
+491517953677
015777953677
02162 - 54 91 44 79
(02162) 54 91 44 79
saddsadasdasd
asdasd
asdasd asdasd asd
asdasd
kjn asohas  asdoiasd
23434 234 234 23
323
23434 234----234
///// ----
// id8834 3493934 //
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have a little enhancement for despecial‘s Regex:

```
(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\(]+\/?){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))
```

It filters numbers that have too high occurrencies of /